# How to include a plain html website in a vaadin application

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, vaadin

I need to embed a plain html website in my vaadin application. My current approach is following.

Add the website content to `src/main/webapp/embedded` directory in my source.

Add a servlet mapping like below, so that requests to `embedded` directory do not go to the vaadin servlet and handled by default servlet of tomcat.

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/embedded/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>VaadinServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Can anyone notice anything wrong in this approach? Or can someone suggest a better way?

Comment: Please define what you mean by "embedd"? The way you did setup it, it just delvers the content of the folder from the same url, but why embedd it in vaadin at all and not use another url?

Comment: Check out the BrowserFrame Component for Vaadin. You can display any Resources in a BrowserFrame.

Comment: @AndréSchild I want to have both vaadin application and the plain html site packaged in the same war file

Comment: Ok, so then this is OK. But the location of your staic content does not matter to vaadin, you can place it where you wish and also use the servlet to map the path in the container.

Answer (score 0):

if you want display the site inside your vaadin application, you can use the BrowserFrame component:

```
String filepath = VaadinServlet.getCurrent().getServletContext().getRealPath("embedded/mysite.html");
File htmlFile = new File(filepath);

FileResource fileResource = new FileResource(htmlFile);

BrowserFrame frame = new BrowserFrame(null, fileResource);
```

Comment: Would this allow links between html pages in the `embedded` directory?